# Why is the Sharepoint List View Threshold disallowing CAML query submitted via lists.asmx in production but not in test?

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I am writing code to synchronize data in a custom app with a Sharepoint 2010 document library via web services calls to lists.asmx.  As part of this sync, I am looking up previously sync'd items in Sharepoint by their GUID, using this CAML query:

```
<query>
<Query xmlns="">

   <Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name="GUID"/>
         <Value Type="Text">{C0BE0DBF-103B-4302-83C8-01BB0B0F6FDD}</Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>

   <QueryOptions>
      <QueryThrottleMode>1</QueryThrottleMode>
      <RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
   </QueryOptions>

</Query>
</query>
```

The document library that this is querying exceeds the List View Threshold.  In my test environment, this was not a problem.  However, in production, this query gets limited by the List View Threshold enforcer:

> The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

This page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813.aspx says:

> Farm administrators and local computer administrators on the front-end Web server, where a query originates, are not blocked by the list view threshold.

but my user in the test environment is not a local computer administrator.  Is there some **other** reason that the List View Threshold would apply in one case and not in another?  Keeping in mind that I have to go over lists.asmx, are there some other ways of getting around this limit?

Thanks!